# how do i do this in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of students, a table of courses and a table containing a studentid and a courseid, I want to find all "student friends", meaning that they do at least two equal courses

Comment: Could you please post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sample data, expected results, *and* you attempts will help us help you. If you haven't tried anything, what research have you done? What didn't you understand about it? Also, what RDBMS are you *really* using? SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products.

Comment: I use SQL Server, i dont know how to do this, i was thinking about to do this with While, and comper one row to all rows in the table;

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH StudentsSubjects AS
  (
      SELECT 1 AS STUDENT_ID,'MATH' AS SUBJECTT
         UNION ALL
      SELECT 1,'ENGLISH'
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 1,'HISTORY'
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 1,'CS'
       UNION ALL
     SELECT 2,'HISTORY'
       UNION ALL
     SELECT 2,'GEO'
       UNION ALL
     SELECT 3,'CS'
       UNION ALL
     SELECT 3,'HISTORY' 

 )
 SELECT X.PRIMARY_STUDENT,X.SECONDARY_STUDENT
 FROM
 (
   SELECT S.STUDENT_ID AS PRIMARY_STUDENT,S.SUBJECTT,S2.STUDENT_ID AS   SECONDARY_STUDENT, 
 ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY S.STUDENT_ID,S2.STUDENT_ID ORDER BY S.STUDENT_ID)D
 FROM StudentsSubjects AS S
 JOIN StudentsSubjects AS S2 ON S.STUDENT_ID<>S2.STUDENT_ID AND     S.SUBJECTT=S2.SUBJECTT
)X WHERE X.D>1
ORDER BY X.PRIMARY_STUDENT
```

Common Table Expression StudentsSubjects  is a substitute for your "a table containing a studentid and a courseid". Replace it with your actual table name